# Python Split file by offset

Tags: python

Hello everyone i have a big file and i want split it by offset

for example

first part file is 0x18--0x181b

second part file is 0x21e4--0x4e4a

what should i do ? i try use f.seek() but failed

```py
def str2hex(Cstring):
    return hex(int(Cstring,16))

def splitfile(filename,start,end):
    global Num
    f = open(filename,"rb+")
    _whence = hex(start - end)[2]
    c = f.seek(start,int(_whence))
    print(str(c))
    with open(filename+"_"+str(Num),"w+"):
        f.write(int.to_bytes(c,byteorder='big'))
        f.close
    Num = Num + 1

splitfile('test',0x181b,0x18)
```

Comment: What is the nature of the failure of `f.seek()`?

Comment: f.seek() returns no data but a four-digit number i don't know why Is there a better 3rd party library or other way to solve this problem ?

Comment: I think you should review the documentation of the [seek](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=seek#io.TextIOBase.seek) function. You seem to be expecting all the wrong things from it currently.

Comment: Could you write out, concretely, what the input file contains? I'm not sure what "part" is supposed to mean in this context.